# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

I am programming a easy program that basically shoots out random words.

But this happened.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

And here is the section of the program that is involved.

```
    key = random.randint(1,tnums)
    print(key)
    self.next = Button(self,text = "Next",command = self.shoot)
    word = f[key]
    self.ins.delete(0.0,END)
    self.ins.insert(0.0,word)
```

Comment: You're not even going to tell us which line has that error?

Answer (score 5):

`f` is a `shelve` object (a dictionary-like structure). `key` is an integer. You then try to look up `key` in `f`, but, according to the [documentation on `shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shelve.html):

> The keys are ordinary strings.

Cast `key` to a string first.

```
key = str(random.randint(1,tnums))
```

Comment: But now the error 
`KeyError: b'3' `Happend

Comment: Then there's no such key in there. You'll have to figure out why your program is selecting wrong keys and adjust the logic as necessary.

Comment: @Jemoka  You have greatly misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Wait what?